# write orwhere for multi tables in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using eloquent as ORM and I want to use `where` in multi-table like this:

```
$raw_query = EntityCity::with(['province']);
        $raw_query = $raw_query->where(function ( $q ) use ( $search_data ) {
            $q->where('city.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%")
            ->orwhere('province.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%");
        });
    }
    $this->data[ 'result_list' ] = $raw_query->limit($this->per_page)
                                             ->orderByDesc("time_insert")
                                             ->offset(( $page_num - 1 ) * $this->per_page)
                                             ->get();
```

However, I encounter the following error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'province.title' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `city` where (`city`.`title` like %fars% or `province`.`title` like %fars%))

If I comment the `orwhere` it works.

So how can you write this with `orwhere`?

Comment: It's not the same my question is how to use orwhere in the joined table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
   $raw_query = $raw_query->where(function ( $q ) use ( $search_data ) {
        $q->where('city.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%")
        ->orwhere('province.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%");
    });
}
```

you should use:

```
$raw_query = $raw_query->where(function($q) {
     $q->where('city.title', 'like', "%$search_data%")
       ->orWhereHas('province', function ( $q ) use ( $search_data ) {
           $q->where('province.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%");
      });
});
```

Notice that the where .. orWhereHas was wrapped here in additional `where` and this gives you confidence you can add any other conditions as for example selecting only active cities:

```
$raw_query = $raw_query->where(function($q) {
     $q->where('city.title', 'like', "%$search_data%")
       ->orWhereHas('province', function ( $q ) use ( $search_data ) {
           $q->where('province.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%");
      });
})->where('active', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `orWhereHas`:

```
$raw_query = $raw_query->where('city.title', 'like', "%$search_data%")
        ->orWhereHas('province', function ( $q ) use ( $search_data ) {
            $q->where('province.title' , 'like' , "%$search_data%");
        });
```